# How to parse js value to php with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to figure out how to get id value from an URL without reloading a .php page. If I understand correctly I have to use ajax to do this. I've tried to use help from the things I've read online, but I just can't make it work. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function f(){
var url = window.location.href;
var params = url.split('?id=');
var id = (params[1]);
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"kalender.php",
        data:{id:id},
        });
   });

<?php
$test=$_POST["id"];
echo $test;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your url looks like: my_path.php?id=512

then you can access it in PHP with:

```
$test = $_GET['id']; // or you can use $_REQUEST['id'];
echo $test
```

What you cannot do is loading a page with php and javascript and expect that the php of that same page will get the ajax result from a call on that same page. Simply because rendering the php is finished before your javascript is loaded in the browser.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Does that mean that it isn't possible to get the id from the URL without refreshing or reloading the page?

Comment: You can do it without ajax as you can see in the answer. in PHP you can directly read the $_GET parameters of the request. You can also get the full request uri with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];